# Ajax error and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, uncaught-exception

I know there has been a thousand topics on this error, but none seem to match my issue.  The usual answers appear to be invalid json or a problem with the datatypes in the ajax call.
All json I send back is from php's json_encode.

My problem seems to be a bit weirder:

I am creating an application and this runs perfectly fine on the server at work (windows server 2008, IIS 7, PHP 5.3), and even locally on a work pc using WAMP, and on my home server which is windows 7 with IIS 7 and PHP 5.4.

However, recently when copying my application over from work to home (via Dropbox - no code changes whatsoever), suddenly every single ajax call made by jQuery is not working correctly... but it also does;

- using console.log(data) I can see that what is being returned is
  exactly what should be.
- but any if statement etc doesn't recognise the value

For example, my login script echos true from php (interpreted by JS as '1') if logged in, and I can see this 1 being sent back with console.log - but JS then doesn't recognise this when I use (data == 1) or data == '1', I'm baffled as to how JS can recognise data in console.log, but not in an if statement on the next line.

I get this same problem for absolutely any ajax call on any page of the application, whether JSON.parse, $.parseJSON or just standard post is being used to decipher the return value.  I have also tried using dataType json for these calls with no success.
When I do try using json datatype I get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token', but no errors at all for standard post and post backs.  All calls work perfectly on the work server.

Here is the ajax success of my login call:

```
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
if (data == 1) {
window.location = (window.lasturl == "" ? "index.php" : window.lasturl);
} else {
$form.after('failed to login, username and password may be incorrect - please try again');
}
```

Where $form is set to the login form.

console.log shows: 1
but the data == 1 if statement is not performed, and the else statement is.

It's doing my head in!

Any ideas?

Comment: is it the full code ?

Comment: `window.lasturl` whats this? Have you define this property somewhere?

Comment: @anurupr it is exactly the code used in the success part of my ajax, the php side is simply: `echo true;`

Comment: what is the line of code that the error says it is occurring on?

Comment: try using parseInt(data) == 1, if dataTypes doesn't match

Comment: try this, `if (data) {`

Comment: `window.lasturl` is defined as the location that the user was redirected from to the login page (usually index.php).  After the `if (data == 1)` statement, there is `else {       $form.after('failed to login, username and password may be incorrect - please try again');
}` - and this line of code is what is activated

Comment: @DJB, please edit your question to contain the code

Comment: Apologies, I have added this now!
pronox I tried parseInt and didn't work unfortunately!
KrishR if (data) does work! so it is obviously getting something

Comment: try `console.log(typeof data)` and post the output

Comment: @anurupr typeof returns `string`

Comment: i see . but like you said `if (data == "1")` doesn't work right?

Comment: I suspect an extra character, can you check `data.length`

Comment: So @DJB are you confident that `typeof data` is `string` ?

Comment: @DJB Also, do you use `?>` to close your php file ? If so I'd recommend you to remove it

Comment: @aduch seems you are right, data.length is 3!
data == "1" does not work, nor does data == true anurupr, there is no error message for this Patrick Evans, I only get errors for json data!

Comment: is it not necessary to close the file with a `?>`? I wasn't aware of this!

Comment: @AmitJoki console.log(typeof data) outputs string

Comment: Well when you output html it is recommended to **have it**. When not, you should remove it because of these kind of problems. Typically when creating a php class, never use `?>` at the end of your class file, because when including it, you may have extra character screwing up your final html if there is an html output.

Comment: ahh I see, good to know! It's just a very odd error as this is only happening on my home server, and everything works fine at work.
@tliokos $.trim(data) did not help unfortunately!

Comment: If your server is a linux distro at work, it can explain things such as line endings problem (cf. `CRLF` and `LF`)

Comment: work server is Windows Server 2008, PHP 5.3 on IIS 7.  I'm not hugely knowledgeable on ajax/post but I understand json issues are pretty common due to encoding/decoding - it's just where I'm simply using echo true, and this not being recognized in an if - only in console.log that is a bit crazy

Comment: try if (parseInt(data,10) === 1)